# setting alternating backgrounds when using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using alot of ajax calls on a page, the problem is i don't know which one will load at any one time as some load faster than others and i'm appending the ajax results to one div when they load.

here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#stage0').load('myscript.php?data=1234567890',function( {$('#data').append(this);});       
$('#stage1').load('myscript.php?data=1234567891',function(){$('#data').append(this);});
$('#stage2').load('myscript.php?data=1234567892',function(){$('#data').append(this);});
$('#stage3').load('myscript.php?data=1234567893',function(){$('#data').append(this);});
$('#stage4').load('myscript.php?data=1234567894',function(){$('#data').append(this);});

}

<div id="data"></div>
<div id='stage0'></div><div id='stage1'></div><div id='stage2'></div><div id='stage3'></div><div id='stage4'></div>
```

I'd like the first result to have a white background then a grey background, then a white background etc...

I thought that maybe I could write an ajax call to look at the ajax result above the one thats just loaded, if it has a white background then set this one to grey. maybe using the closest call to look it up? http://api.jquery.com/closest/

am i on the right track? how do you think i should i write the javascript?

Comment: What does `myscript` return, and how is that related to setting backgrounds?

Comment: it returns some html thats displayed to the user, i could set the background in myscript but i'd only be able to use one color for the background...not alternate it?

Answer (score 0):

Make a class

```
<style>
    .blue { background-color: blue; }
</style>
```

and then add to your functions:

```
$('body').toggleClass("blue")
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by using :odd and :even

http://jsfiddle.net/LBPcC/

```
$('.bg:odd').addClass("grey")
$('.bg:even').addClass("white")
```